# Module Parse failed: Unexpected token with babel-loader for BABEL_ENV=development

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, webpack, babel-loader

Using `yarn` I recently added the `@superset-ui/embedded-sdk` library to my react project that is using webpack to build. When we run our prod build everything seems fine, but for our dev build it is failing to compile. I don't fully understand webpack so it's hard for me to figure out how to move forward. I have tried upgrading some dependencies but that doesn't seem to do anything.

The only thing that I have managed to narrow it down to is if I change my `BABEL_ENV=development` in my script file to `BABEL_ENV=production` then it seems to compile and run fine. What can my next steps be in order to try and resolve the issue?

Here is the actual error -

```
./node_modules/@superset-ui/embedded-sdk/lib/index.js 74:45
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (74:45)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|       const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
|       const dashboardConfig = dashboardUiConfig ? `?uiConfig=${calculateConfig()}` : "";
>       const filterConfig = dashboardUiConfig?.filters || {};
|       const filterConfigKeys = Object.keys(filterConfig);
|       const filterConfigUrlParams = filterConfigKeys.length > 0 ? "&" + filterConfigKeys.map(key => _const.DASHBOARD_UI_FILTER_CONFIG_URL_PARAM_KEY[key] + '=' + filterConfig[key]).join('&') : ""; // set up the iframe's sandbox configuration
```

Answer (score 0):

Error here: const filterConfig = dashUiConfig?.filters || {};
The solution is to go to \node_modules@superset-ui\embedded-sdk\lib\index.js and edit this code to

```
const filterConfig = dashboardUiConfig && dashboardUiConfig.filters ? dashboardUiConfig.filters : {};
```

Comment: You can even use `dashboardUiConfig.filters ?? {}` instead of `dashboardUiConfig.filters ? dashboardUiConfig.filters : {}`